# UserControl in AJAX ModalPopupExtender in another UserControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I am working on a ASP.NET (with Visual Basic) web application.

I have been trying to make a user control for two days, but i have an issue that i could not solve.

I have a FormView that I want to fill with an object, that i get from another user control. This second user control must be shown in a ModalPopupExtender when I click on an ImageButton. This works correctly. However, when i use the control, the modal popup is closed.

I use the same user control in a ModalPopupExtender, in others .aspx pages, and it works correctly, so I don't think that the error comes from it. It fails only when the user control and ModalPopupExtender are used in another control.

I show you some screenshots to explain easier :

www.noelshack.com/2012-39-1348649045-1.png

1 : .aspx web page,
2 : Button which shows the popup,
3 : .ascx user control,
4 : Button which closes the popup

This configuration works correctly : I can use my user control and the popup is closed only when it must be.

www.noelshack.com/2012-39-1348649045-2.png

1 : .ascx user control,
2 : ImageButton which shows the popup,
3 : .ascx user control,
4 : Button which closes the popup

The popup with the control is correctly opened, but when i try to search with the control (click on "RECHERCHER"), the popup is closed.

www.noelshack.com/2012-39-1348649045-3.png

Then, if I click again on the ImageButton that shows the popup

www.noelshack.com/2012-39-1348649045-4.png

We can see that the user control worked correctly.
So the only problem is that the popup is closed when I try to use the user control.
And this occurs only when i work in another user control, it works correctly in a page.

Here is the part of my code where i use the popup and the user control :

In the page, which works :

www.noelshack.com/2012-39-1348649045-6.png

In the user control, which does not work :

www.noelshack.com/2012-39-1348649044-5.png

You can ask me if you don't understand something or if you need more explanations
Thank you for your help and sorry for my english. Sorry for the links, I can't post images or hyperlinks...

Comment: +1 for such an excellent description, but honestly, i havent read it. Sorry mate !

Comment: Screenshots aren't rendering. Take a another stab at formatting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following at the bottom of the RECHERCHER button:

```
mymodalpopupextender.show()
```

Comment: Hi Kjartan. +1 for your answer. However this button is private in the user control, and no event is fired when clicked, so i don't see where i can call this method.